# Nodejs dev environnement with docker volumes

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

I m a nodejs developer and I need to try it with docker.

Actually, I m always working with TDD :

- Red test
- Green test
- Refactor
- Green test
- Functionnal verifications (starting a server, checking that all the things are ok)

I was wondering, how can I process to launch my test inside of a container, and run the server as I want (like stop / start it) directly inside of a container, without using ssh ?

Does anybody has an idea how can I have my dev environnement working with docker ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You normally wouldn't restart from within the container, just restart the container as node should be PID 1. You can run TDD tests as part of the Dockerfile `build` or `docker exec` into the container to run tests during dev. Ultimately, you probably want to run your tests on build for a reliable production workflow.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't quite understand your requirement. I did something myself. My requirement was a webapp developemnt env with dockers.

Please feel free to checkout this repo It might help.

https://github.com/fchwpo/fibo-dock-cci

Comment: The user asked, _how can I process to launch my test inside of a container, and run the server as I want (like stop / start it) directly inside of a container, without using ssh?_. The answer you posted doesn't help the user reach an answer as you have given nothing on how to solve his problem. If you are bit confused on his requirements, try posting a comment on the question instead of answering the question. Ask the user on things you are unclear about so you can help the user with his question.